# How to search in for a particular text in range of cell

Tags: excel

I'm using this formula to search particular text in a cell and does work returning correct value, but is there a way to specify range of cells instead just one?

This works `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Test",A2)),"Yes","No")`
Wanted to see if something like `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Test",A2:A100)),"Yes","No")` is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(CountIf(A2:A100,"Test"),"Yes","No")
```

**Update**

```
=IF( SumProduct(A2:A100=B1) ,"Yes","No")
```

or this array formula ( enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> )

```
=IF( A2:A100=B1 ,"Yes","No")
```

It will not work with wildcard characters and will not work for comparing text to number for example.

Comment: this works almost as expected, but my cell is having test+character something like "Test#1" and seems having the number and character doesn't evaluate it properly. Any way to search/compare number along with text? thank you for you help.

Comment: Do you mean the # is any digit from 0 to 9? You can use `"Test?1"`, but `?` will match any character.

Comment: No actually I'm using "#" as a sign to specify number. But using the wildcard character you suggested worked as expected, but again I cannot bind a cell like =IF(CountIf(A2:A100, B1),"Yes","No") I have to specify string to make it work. If you have any suggestions if we can specify cell please let me or else thank you very much for taking time and suggesting and helping.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH("Test",A2:A100),0))>0,"Yes","No")
```

and then make it an array formula by hitting Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Comment: Thank for taking time and suggesting Matt, I really appreciate it.